# Wordpress Login Form with Google reCaptcha v3

Tags: javascript, wordpress, authentication, themes, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Google reCaptcha v3 on my Wordpress default Login form.  The situation is as follows:

- My current host enforces Google reCaptcha v2 just prior to wp-login.php being loaded, however, this is done by scripting on the host side, and I may wish to move the project in the future, so I need the option of enabling reCaptcha.
- I want to implement v3 as it doesn't impact the workflow of users on the project, and while I'm on the current host, they already have to check the v2 checkbox to get to the login form.
- I have already set up settings in the Theme to store the site key and secret key, so I can just call them into variables

The issue seems to be that the script being used to add the "action" and "token" fields isn't working properly, as these fields should be added on the forms submission, and values entered for them just prior to it being submitted, but it doesn't.  Here is my function:

```
function eh_login_scripts() {   
$site_key = esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'eh_gcaptcha_sitekey' ) );
if( !empty( $site_key ) && !is_null( $site_key ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'grecaptcha-v3',
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=' . $site_key,
        array( 'jquery' ),
        NULL,
        false
    ); ?>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#loginform" ).submit( function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
                
            grecaptcha.ready(function() {
                grecaptcha.execute( <?php echo $site_key; ?>, {action: 'ehwplogin' } ).then(function( token ) {
                    $( '#loginform' ).prepend( '<p><input type="hidden" name="token" value="' + token + '"></p>' );
                    $( '#loginform' ).prepend( '<p><input type="hidden" name="action" value="ehwplogin"></p>' );
                    $( '#loginform' ).unbind( 'submit' ).submit();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php }
```

}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'eh_login_scripts' );

As far as I can tell, the Google JS is loaded successfully (I can see it in the source, and the reCaptcha badge is displayed in the corner of the page).  After submitting an attempt to login, I output the $_POST data, and it doesn't show the "action" or "token" fields, and that obviously then fails my verification function and returns an error.

Can anyone help me with where I am going wrong on the code to enter these fields please?